# Java invoking method requiring vararg

Tags: java, variadic-functions, invoke

So I have method more or less like this:

```
foo(Boolean a, Boolean b, Integer... excess)
```

and I want to invoke it with array of arguments that contains at least first 2 booleans and not always rest of integers. I've tried creating array of objects and put it on the end but then it throws Exception cuz it cant cast array of object to integer, dont know why so I ask, is there any easy way of doing this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried. *'it throws Exception'* -- what exception?

Comment: you might have used `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`

Comment: damn, too early posted, I wanted to include that I do it in reflection and it goes like this
method.invoke(cl, list.toArray())
this list had plain list of arguments, 2 logic and Integer[], 2 login and Object[] but nothing worked in case where list contains excess integers and where it does not

Comment: You can always *edit* the question, its not too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method declaration for the *mandatory* and *optional* parameters are correct but in fact if you want to use an **object array** for the optional parameter part then you should be using definin `Object... args` as your final parameter to the method.

In your question you said you tried to create array of objects and passed this to the method as the final parameter but your declaration is `Integer... args` which is equivalent to `Integer[] args` so you have to declare and pass an `Integer[]` to the method.

Comment: finally, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you defined foo method like below.

```
void foo(Boolean a, Boolean b, Integer... excess) {

}
```

Since varargs can take zero or more arguments, you can call that either passing integer array or not.

**Example 1:**

```
Integer[] arr = { 2, 3, 5 };
foo(true, false, arr);
```

**Example 2**

```
foo(true, false);
```

Find below sample app.

```
public class App {

    private static void foo(Boolean a, Boolean b, Integer... excess) {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer[] arr = { 2, 3, 5 };

        foo(true, false, arr);
        foo(true, false);
    }
}
```

I would recommend you to read varargs [here](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2014/02/varargs-methods-with-variable-number-of.html).